# Catching errors in LFTP Bash Script

Tags: bash, lftp

So I am trying to catch specific errors whilst transferring files using LFTP, but the problem is, I am unable to catch them due to calling the `<<EOF` to allow interfacing with the interactive shell.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
#Start backup procedure
lftp<<EOF
open ftps://$HOST || bye && #SEND MAIL CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER (ERROR)
login $USER $PASSWORD || #SEND MAIL AUTH FAILURE (ERROR)
#Remove existing backups on FTP server
glob -a rm -r ./* || bye && #SEND MAIL FAILED (WARNING) TO REMOVE PREVIOUS BACKUPS
#Upload new backup to FTP server
lcd /var/opt/gitlab/backups
mput *.tar || bye && #SEND EMAIL (ERROR) FAILED TO UPLOAD FILES
bye
EOF
```

Obviously when bye is called the interactive session is closed, but nothing gets executed after the &&.

Anyone have any idea on how to do specific error catching like this?

Comment: have you tried using traps instead of the `||` and `&&` operators ?

Comment: I suspect you are going to need to turn to `Tcl/expect` to get that level of checking.

Comment: @Aserre - Haven't tried that yet, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command grouping using parentheses:

```
open... || (shell send-mail; exit 1)
```